# R path with multiple variables

Tags: r, path, operators, relational

I have a handful of directories and files in this format

```
/home/scratch/test/123/local/test.vcf.gz
/home/scratch/test/456/local/test.vcf.gz
/home/scratch/test/789/local/test.vcf.gz
```

I have a snippet of code that basically points to these directories and combines all the test.vcf.gz into Rdata but this part of the code throws an error

```
dat = read_csv("input.csv") %>% 
  gather(pipeline, id,  `SRS`) %>% 
  mutate(pipeline_clean = c("SRS" = "main")[pipeline]) %>% 
  mutate(output = sprintf("/home/scratch/test/%s/local/%s", id)) %>% 
  mutate(Group.Id = sprintf("%s_%s_%s_%s", prep, platform, pipeline_clean, ref))

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `output`.
x too few arguments
ℹ Input `output` is `sprintf(...)`.
```

But when I change the output directory to `/home/scratch/test/123/local/%s`, it does not throw any error. I assumed I could provide a path for multiple variables with `%s`, any suggestion would be helpful.

thankyou

Comment: You had two `%s` and only one input `id`.  I think you need `mutate(output = sprintf("/home/scratch/test/%s/local/%s", id, id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to interpolate the same value multiple times i.e. `%s` is repeated twice, we need to repeat the arguments in `sprintf`

```
...
  mutate(output = sprintf("/home/scratch/test/%s/local/%s", id, id)) %>%
...
```

If the suffix is always `test.vcf.gz`, then we can remove the last `%s`

```
  mutate(output = sprintf("/home/scratch/test/%s/local/test.vcf.gz", id))
```